# How is EasyEditSpan used in Android to allow partial text editing?

Tags: android, textview

I want to allow the user to edit just part of a line of text in my Android app. I see a class called the EasyEditSpan but when I stick it into a TextView nothing happens. I tried making the TextView editable but it still doesn't have any effect. If switch to an EditText then the whole line of text is editable which is also incorrect. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView testView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    testView.setText(buildMiddleEditSpannable("Please enter your ", "Name", " here."));
}

public static Spannable buildMiddleEditSpannable(CharSequence beginning, CharSequence middle, CharSequence end) {
    int spanMidStart = beginning.length();
    int spanMidEnd = spanMidStart + middle.length();

    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(new StringBuilder(middle).insert(0, beginning).append(end));
    span.setSpan(new EasyEditSpan(), spanMidStart, spanMidEnd, 0);
    return span;
}
```

Comment: What is the Android version your app target to run? Note that [EasyEditSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/EasyEditSpan.html) is really new introduced since API Level 14. It may break on old android system, even though you should get some error exception in Logcat.

Comment: I am running and testing on Ice Cream Sandwich or higher only.

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the framework code referring to `EasyEditSpan` ([EasyEditSpan](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/style/EasyEditSpan.java), [TextView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) and [TextUtils](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java)), it become apparent that even though it says in its description:

> Provides an easy way to edit a portion of text.

The currently available functionality is limited to just the second part of the description as follow:

> The TextView uses this span to allow the user to delete a chuck of text in one click. the text. TextView removes this span as soon as the text is edited, or the cursor moves.

Here's some quick sample code that demonstrates its use:

```
public class EasyEditSpanActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        setContentView(editText);

        showToast("Longclick to set EasyEditSpan for the line on cursor");

        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        editText.setSingleLine(false);
        editText.setText("####\n#######\n###\n######\n####".replace("#", "text "));
        editText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Layout layout = editText.getLayout();
                final int line = layout.getLineForOffset(editText.getSelectionStart());
                final int start = layout.getLineStart(line);
                final int end = layout.getLineEnd(line);
                editText.getEditableText().setSpan(new EasyEditSpan(), start, end,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                showToast("Edit line to show EasyEdit window");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

So unfortunately if you need a way to allow the user to edit just part of a line of text in your app, `EasyEditSpan` does not seem to help much. It is likely you will need to implement some code utilizing `ClickableSpan` and probably a custom dialog.

Comment: Looking at the code in TextView, I could not see how EasyEditSpan made anything easy to edit. Even the Javadoc says it only allows the deletion of text.

Answer (score 4):

You might be better of using ClickableSpan and popup a dialog to edit the content. However, I tried to implement partially editable textview. This is not complete and may have some rough edges. It uses  three spans and overrides onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) and onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) methods to disable edits while the target is part1 or part3. Hope it helps.

//activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.sensei.partialedit.EditTextSelectable
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="#00000000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

//MainActivity.java

```
package com.sensei.partialedit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditTextSelectable testView = (EditTextSelectable) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        testView.setText("Please enter your ", " Name ", " here.");
    }
}
```

//EditTextSelectable.java

```
package com.sensei.partialedit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.method.KeyListener;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditTextSelectable extends EditText {

    private String part1;
    private String part2;
    private String part3;
    private ForegroundColorSpan span1;
    private CharacterStyle span2;
    private ForegroundColorSpan span3;

    public EditTextSelectable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setTag(getKeyListener());
    }

    public EditTextSelectable(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTag(getKeyListener());
    }

    public EditTextSelectable(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTag(getKeyListener());
    }

    public void setText(String part1, String part2, String part3) {
        setText(buildMiddleEditSpannable(part1, part2, part3));
        setSelection(part1.length() + part2.length() - 1);
    }

    private Spannable buildMiddleEditSpannable(String part1, String part2,
            String part3) {
        this.part1 = part1;
        this.part2 = part2;
        this.part3 = part3;
        SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(part1
                + part2 + part3);
        span1 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY);
        spannable.setSpan(span1, 0, part1.length() - 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span2 = new UnderlineSpan();
        spannable.setSpan(span2, part1.length(),
                part1.length() + part2.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        span3 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY);
        spannable.setSpan(span3, (part1 + part2).length(),
                (part1 + part2 + part3).length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return spannable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        if (part1 == null)
            return;
        if (selStart >= getText().getSpanStart(span2)
                && selEnd <= getText().getSpanEnd(span2)) {
            setKeyListener((KeyListener) getTag());
            setCursorVisible(true);
        } else {
            setKeyListener(null);
            setCursorVisible(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            // Just ignore the [Enter] key
            return true;
        }
        int selectionStart = getSelectionStart();
        int selectionEnd = getSelectionEnd();
        Log.d("partialedit", "OnKeyDown:" + selectionStart + ":" + selectionEnd + ":" + getText().getSpanStart(span2) + ":" + getText().getSpanEnd(span2));
        if (selectionStart < part1.length() + 1
            || selectionStart >= getText().length() - part3.length()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle all other keys in the default way
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```